# php mysql RAND() in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I made page with all profiles. Every 3 rows I inserting a Premium block between results. I have 12 rows on page and 4 premium blocks between every 3 rows. I need to show random users with premium='1' row from mysql every foreach loop.

```
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) as premiumCount FROM users WHERE premium='1'");
    $sth->execute();
    $answer = $sth->fetch();
    $premium = $answer['premiumCount'];
    $sth2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active='1' AND block='0' ORDER BY premium DESC LIMIT 12");
    $sth2->execute();
    $result = $sth2->fetchAll();
    foreach ($results as $answer) {
         // getting user info
       if ($premium > 0) {
            $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE premium='1' ORDER BY RAND()");
            // getting premium user info
       }
     }
```

This code is work, but it can be 2-3 same premium blocks on page (I need 4 different blocks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select as many random premium users as you need *before the loop with one query* (you can add `LIMIT 4` to your query) instead of selecting repeatedly inside the loop. That way you can be sure you won't have duplicates.

Fetch the results and store them in an array, and where you're running the `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE premium='1'...` query inside the loop, use a value from the array instead. You can use `array_pop` to get values so you won't have to mess with a counter or anything like that to keep track of your position in the array.

```
// getting premium user info
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE premium='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
$sth->execute();
$premium = $sth->fetchAll();

foreach ($results as $answer) {
     // getting user info
   if ($premium) {
        $premium_row = array_pop($premium);
   }
 }
```